# Error in SED Directory Creation

Tags: bash, sed, cat

I'm trying to use SED to create a series of directories that all contain a file of the same name, yet each file in each directory varies by one line.

```
for i in $( cat ~/SCRIPTS/AALIST.txt);  do

mkdir ~/jan10/25

sed -e "s/HAT/${i}/"  <~/SCRIPTS/HAT25.inp > ~/jan10/25/25$i/mat.inp
```

AALIST.txt is simply a file containing, effectively..

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Whereas HAT25.inp has many lines of text, and then the word "HAT" on the 25th line, this HAT should be replaced with A,B,C, etc. In directory 25, SED should be creating directories called 25A, 25B, 25C, etc. Inside of these directories should be the original HAT25.inp file with HAT replaced with the letter of the parent directory. By this, I mean that the directory 25A should contain HAT.inp renamed mat.inp and containing A at the 25th line, rather than HAT. Unfortunately, when I try to execute my code above, I get the error:

```
cannot create directory `/home/user/jan10/25': File exists
./loop.sh: line 23: /home/user/jan10/25/25$i/mat.inp: No such file or directory
```

Is there any insight on what I've done wrong, I'm having trouble determining exactly what error I've made.

EDIT:

By commenting out the mkdir line, I now receive the following error. The directory "25" is created, but directories 25A, 25B, etc. are not created.  The error received is below.

```
./loop.sh: line 23: /home/user/jan10/25/25A/mat.inp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: you realize that your `mkdir` is inside your loop, and is executed during each loop, hence the `cannot create dir ...`. ? Maybe you really want `mkdir ~/jan10/25/$i` ?   The `25/25$i` error is a bit mysterious. Given your code I wouldn't expect this. Is the the real code that is being executed? Good luck.

Comment: You're right, the mkdir definitely shouldn't be in the loop, but the problem persists even when that is commented out. The directory 25 is created, but none of the subdirectories (25A, 25B, etc.) is created. The error I now receive has been edited above!

Comment: I really think the main source of your problem is that you want `mkdir ~/jan10/25/$i`, right? Using that will probably fix the other errors.

Comment: Ah how foolish of me, yes you're right shellter! Submit an answer, that was exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in $( cat ~/SCRIPTS/AALIST.txt )
 do

   NewFolder=~/jan10/25/25${i}
   mkdir "${NewFolder}"

   sed -e "s/HAT/${i}/" ~/SCRIPTS/HAT25.inp > "${NewFolder}/mat.inp"

done
```

- Your code was missing some info (end of loop, folder end name at creation and mayb some space in `$()`
- some enhancemnet (sed don't need a `<` and can directly take the file as parameter (avoid a subshell), use of surrounding `{}` for variable

Comment: @George: This is even better, so please accept it. Good luck to all.

Comment: This works well, but preceeding the code I added a simply command to actually make the numbered directory, without "mkdir ~/jan10/25" it will not work unless the directory already exist, Cheers, this code worked great!